# Dropwizard 0.7.0 : Testing Hibernate backed resources

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, dropwizard

I'm developing on Dropwizard 0.7.0 and followed the document and example mentioned in the [Dropwizard site](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/index.html)

In the same I'm using Hibernate for database related operations.

My resources are working. Now I would like to create unit tests for the same. For writing the same I want to set-up DB, perform tests and tear-down DB.

I tried to follow the example mentioned in some of the projects using JDBI to see whether the same can be used with Hibernate or not.In those projects JDBI DAO objects are being mocked and used for testing. The similar mocking approach is not working for Hibernate.

I also checked the projects like to see how they are doing the tests:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/MAqh9OLJkyc

https://gist.github.com/carlo-rtr/4081457

From the discussion around the above it seems we need to spin server. 
Is spinning dropwizard the only solution for doing such unit testing? Or the process is simplified in version 0.7.0? If it is simplified, would like to have a reference for the same.

many thanks

pradeep